# How to add isset $ _GET Multiple Functions in PHP

Tags: php, isset

The code below always displays an error message:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: p in **C:\xampp\htdocs\school\content.php** on line **2**
>   **Notice:** Undefined index: p in **C:\xampp\htdocs\school\content.php** on line **2**
>   **Notice:** Undefined index: p in **C:\xampp\htdocs\school\content.php** on line **6**

```
<?php

    if($_GET['p'] == "home" || !$_GET['p']){
        echo "<title>Welcome to Homepage</title>";
    }elseif($_GET['p'] == "about"){
        echo "<title>ABOUT | $schoolname</title>";
    }if($_GET['p'] == "contact"){
        echo "<title>CONTACT US | $schoolname</title>";
    }

?>
```

I added the isset, but does not work well. for the error message is gone, but ..

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['p']) and $_GET['p'] == "home" || !isset($_GET['p']) and !$_GET['p'] ){
        echo "<title>Welcome to Homepage</title>";
    }elseif(isset($_GET['p']) and $_GET['p'] == "about"){
        echo "<title>ABOUT | $schoolname</title>";
    }if(isset($_GET['p']) and $_GET['p'] == "contact"){
        echo "<title>CONTACT US | $schoolname</title>";
    }

?>
```

which appears in the title bar is **http: // localhost / school** ..
I want like this, if it is on the homepage: "Welcome to Homepage".

Thaanksss...

Comment: wrap your whole block with `if(isset($_GET['p'])){` and remove it from the inner parts, i would also use a `switch` statement instead of `if else if else if else`

Comment: also, if you don't want notices to appear, then you need to go into php.ini and set your error reporting accordingly.  it's good to keep them on in a development environment.

Comment: You last if should be replaced by else if, or simply remove the conditions and make it an else.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want the homepage triggered on either `$_GET['p']=='home'` OR `!isset($_GET['p'])`, you can do this:

```
$title = "Welcome to the Homepage";

if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    if ($_GET['p'] == "about")
        $title = "About | $schoolname";
    elseif ($_GET['p'] == "contact")
        $title = "CONTACT US | $schoolname";   
}

echo "<title>$title</title>";
```

This will make the default page the homepage, and will only change if `$_GET['p']` is set to `about` or `contact`

Answer (score 1):

be careful when using OR, preferably enclosing your terms with parenthesis conditions, but is cleaner code as follows

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){
      if( $_GET['p'] == "home" ){
          echo "<title>Welcome to Homepage</title>";
      }elseif($_GET['p'] == "about"){
          echo "<title>ABOUT | $schoolname</title>";
      }if( $_GET['p'] == "contact"){
          echo "<title>CONTACT US | $schoolname</title>";
      }
    }else{
         echo "<title>Welcome to Homepage</title>";
    }

?>
```

or

```
  <?php
    $message=array("hombe"=>"Welcome to Homepage","about"=>"ABOUT | $schoolname","contact"=>"CONTACT US | $schoolname");
    if(isset($_GET['p'],$message[$_GET['p']])){
           echo "<title>".$message[$_GET['p']]."</title>";
    }else{
         echo "<title>Welcome to Homepage</title>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$pgdata = array();
$pgdata['home'] = array(
  'title'=>'Title for Home page',
);
$pgdata['about'] = array(
  'title'=>'Title for About Me page',
);
$pgdata['contact'] = array(
  'title'=>'Title for Contact',
);
$pgname = isset($_GET['pg']) ? trim(strip_tags($_GET['pg'])) : 'home';
$title = $pgdata[$pgname]['title'];
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header id="header">
 <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
</header>
<section id="posts">
 <nav id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="home.php" title="Home page">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="home.php?pg=about" title="About Me">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="home.php?pg=Contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your approach you will have a new `elseif` statement with every new title. Just store your titles in an array or fetch them from database, like this:

```
$titles = [
    'default' => '<title>Welcome to Homepage</title>',
    'about' => "<title>ABOUT | $schoolname</title>",
    'contact' => "<title>CONTACT US | $schoolname</title>",
];
```

After that you can display any title by simply using this code:

```
if (!array_key_exists('p', $_GET) || !array_key_exists($_GET['p'], $titles)){
    echo $titles['default'];
} else {
    echo $titles[$_GET['p']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition might not do what you expect. Others have offered solutions, I will show you what results from `x and y || a and b`: this code

```
function tt($msg, $b=true) {
  echo 'Call to tt ',$msg,' returning ', ($b)?'True':'False', "\n"; 
  return $b;
 }

if (tt('isset1') and tt('value1') || tt('isset2') and tt('value2')) 
   {echo "Expression is true\n";} else {echo "Expression is false\n";}
```

results in

```
Call to tt isset1 returning True
Call to tt value1 returning True
Call to tt value2 returning True
Expression is true
```

So the expression following the or operator is skipped.